# Java annotation negation logic

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a Java annotation with reverse / inverse / negation logic.

For e.g., I created a filter in Javax:

```
@Provider
@AuthBinding
public class AuthServerFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {   

@Override   
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {...}
```

And created `AuthBinding` annotation as:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface AuthBinding {

}
```

So , the above filter will be triggered for only the rest resources with the annotation `@AuthBinding`.

Is it possible to create an annotation, so that above filter is applied on all the rest resources except the ones which have annotation.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such frameworks work by explicitly marking "things". The framework scans classes, objects, methods for annotations, and then runs the corresponding code.

There is no notion of "if an annotation X isn't given, then do this or that, depending on X".

And not it is not only technology here. It is a bad design idea! Especially in such a REST resource context, your readers expect that looking at the resource tells them all they need to know about it.

Well, one option exists: you can of of course configure your own filters or interceptors. And those could check if a selected resource does have or not have a specific annotation on it before doing this or that.